# How to use a variable's result from one class in another in python?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm new to python and I'm working on the following code. Of course this is not the best code but it's currently what I know. Overall, the class Database contains a method called log_in() where we have a variable called login_code. When the user logs in using that method, login_code stores the code that the user enters, after this, the class Logged gets executed and when it runs I want to see what user is logged in from a method called who(). Thank you

```
class Database:
    def clear_console(self):
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        return self

    def txt_menu(self):
        self.clear_console()
        terms_conditions()
        checking = input("> Proceed? ")
        if checking == "a":
            self.clear_console()
            self.user_menu()
        else:
            self.txt_menu()

    def loading_bar(self):
        for _ in tqdm(range(101), "> Loading. . .", ncols=75):
            time.sleep(0.01)
        print("> Complete. . .")
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        return self

    def user_menu(self):
        print("")
        process = input("> Are you registered y/n? Or forgot details 'f': ")
        if process == "y":
            self.log_in()
        elif process == "n":
            self.user_registration()
        elif process == "f":
            self.forgot_details()
        else:
            print("Try again! ")
            self.user_menu()

    def user_registration(self):
        global registration_code
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("> To register enter the details below: \n")
        registration_username = input("> Username: ")
        registration_email = input("> Email: ")
        registration_password = input("> Password: ")

        for pwd in range(1):
            registration_code = ""
        for c in range(5):
            registration_code += random.choice(chars)

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tst (username, email, password, code) values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       registration_username, registration_email, registration_password, registration_code)
        print("> Your code is: ", registration_code)
        print("> Successful registration")
        print("")
        print("> Welcome", registration_username)
        conn.commit()
        return

    def log_in(self):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        login_code = input("Enter the code: ")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tst WHERE code = ?", login_code)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if not data:
            print('> Not found')
            self.log_in()
        else:
            cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM tst WHERE code = ?", login_code)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            reducing_string = str(data)[1:-1]
            last_cut = str(reducing_string)[1:-1]
            print("")
            print("Welcome", last_cut)
            return login_code

    def forgot_details(self):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        login_username = input("> Username: ")
        login_password = input("> Password: ")
        cursor.execute("SELECT code FROM tst WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", login_username, login_password)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if not data:
            self.forgot_details()
        else:
            reduction = str(data)[1:-1]
            self.loading_bar()
            print("> Your details are: ", str(reduction)[1:-1])
            print("> To log in enter the code below: ")
            self.log_in()
        conn.commit()


class Logged:
    def who(self):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM tst WHERE code = ?", #NOT SURE WHAT TO WRITE HERE)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Welcome user called: "data)
        conn.commit()

    def login_menu(self):
        print("")
        print("> Choose one of the following: ")
        print("> 1: One \n"
              "> 2: Two \n"
              "> 3: Three \n"
              "> 4: Four")

        user_ask = input("> : ")
        if user_ask == "1":
            print("One")
        elif user_ask == "2":
            print("Two")
        elif user_ask == "3":
            print("Three")
        elif user_ask == "4":
            print("Four")
        else:
            self.login_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue:

> ```
> def log_in(self):
>    cursor = conn.cursor()
>    login_code = input("Enter the code: ")
> ```

This does not store the `login_code` variable to be retrieved later. `login_code` is only available during the execution of `log_in()`. To save it for later, you need to explicitly make `login_code` a member of some object (or make it an object in its own right in a higher scope). This might mean using `self.login_code`, or it might mean making `login_code` a member of some other object that is a member of the `Database` object.

If you want `login_code` to be a member of the `Database` class, you must explicitly refer to it as `self.login_code`. Python doesn't automatically include the object's member variables in the scope of methods like C++ (and Java?) do.

> after this, the class Logged gets executed and when it runs I want to see what user is logged in from a method called who().

You could

- Make `login_code` a global variable and use its value in the `Logged.who()` method. This is probably a bad idea.
- Make `login_code` a member of the `Database` class and make the database instance a member of `Logged` so it can be fetched.
- Make `login_code` a member of `Logged` and give the `Database` class a way to set it when executing the `log_in` method.
- Make `login_code` a member of some other object that is passed as an argument to `Database.log_in()` and `Logger.who()` so that it can be accessed from both methods.

Comment: i was trying to do option 2,3,4 however for some reasons they didn't work :(

Comment: @daily_vlad nobody can tell you what you did wrong with those approaches until you share the code where you do it that way.